# Run SSIS job from SSRS report button?

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssis, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I'm probably sure it can't be done, but I'll check with you guys anyways.

We have and `SSIS` job and an `SSRS` report. The `SSIS` job generates data from a remote system to our local server; the `SSRS` report reports on the local data generated from the `SSIS` job.

The data coming from the SSIS job changes countless times daily, but the SSIS job only updates hourly. So let's say that the job ran at 7:01AM and a user generates the report at 7:50AM. There's a good possibility that the data may have changed in those 49 minutes.

So I had two options:
1. Execute the SSIS job from the stored procedure used for the report. So when I invoke the report, the SP will first execute the SSIS job and update the data, then it will do the SELECT statement that returns the report data. The problem here is that the SSIS job takes a few seconds, so it will seem that the report's slow.

2. Add some button to the SSRS report that will execute the SSIS job. That way, if the user gets obsolete results in the report, he can invoke the SSIS job and run the report again.

So I'm leaning towards the 2nd one, but I don't know if I can add another button to the report that will execute an SSIS job. I also want to use SSRS for this (ie. not create a webform that displays the report).

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: How complex is the SSIS job? Is it just copying data? You might want to look into some kind of replication setup instead of manually copying data every hour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Talking about the second choise, you can create a `@RunJob` parameter maybe `Boolean` type, then in dataset validate if user has selected `True` for running the job. You should set default value to `False` to avoid every time the report is generated the job be executed.

[image]

In the dataset query use `sp_start_job` stored procedure to run the job that execute your SSIS packages if the parameter `@RunJob` is True, otherwise just retrieve the report data.

> While this can help you to get what you need, I don't recommend you to
>   use SSRS for your purpose since it is not designed to affect anyway
>   the underlying database.

Let me know if this can help you.

Comment: To achieve the 'Refresh Button' effect. You could hide this parameter,  and add a textbox with "Refresh Data" on that has an action set to 'Go to report'; setting this parameter to True.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a **parameter** to determine whether or not to run the Stored Procedure. Have the default as **NO**.

Add a line in the beginning of your dataset that checks the parameter and runs the SP if necessary (parameter = yes)

```
IF @RUN_SP = 'YES'
  EXEC SP_Refresh_Data
```

If a user wants to refresh, he changes the parameter to **YES** and re-runs it.

Answer (score 0):

You could build an ASP.NET page that runs the SSIS package; I think by calling the sp_start_job procedure mentioned in a previous answer in the page_load function.
You could then call the page from the SSRS report, for example by setting the action of a text box to the url of the page.
I think that would work!